# debugging javascript in php applications using visual studio

Tags: php, javascript, visual-studio, debugging

i have installed wamp server and vsphp and my development environment is Visual Studio 2008. I was easily able to debug java script by turning on script debugging in IE, however now i have a java script which calls a php script and processes it's output, i want to know how in visual studio can i do that, so that it can execute php code behind (no need for debugging) and then continue processing the javascript code.

Answer (score 1):

Not in VS, but with Firefox you can use [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/1843), a Firefox's add-on which allow you to debug the JS, using breakpoints, spies, and so on. Hope it helps =)

Answer (score 0):

I am one of the developers of VS.Php :) Since this is very product specific if might be better to talk via E-Mail or via customer support forums.

Greetings

```
Thomas Schaaf
schaaf|at|komola.de
```